# Core data constraint work wrongly after close and open application (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working on my assignment. Basically the application will keep tracking the activities that I've done.
I'm using core data to keep track records, the constraint is applied for title because I don't want to keep the same activities tracked (picture of core data is shown as below)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEySx.jpg

When I run on the first time, everything work fine. However, after I close the app and run it again, the constraint work wrongly as I add the totally new activity but it always show that the activity already exists in core data.

The weird thing is that it shows the NSConstraintConflict of other entity (Slang) as shown below:

> Track already existed in coredata Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133021 "(null)" UserInfo={conflictList=(
>       "NSConstraintConflict (0x7f9721c9cf00) for constraint (\n    word\n): database:  (entity: Slang; id: 0xd000000000040000  ; data: ), conflictedObjects: (\n    \" (entity: Slang; id: 0xd0000000018c0000  ; data: {\n    explain = \\"Excellent! Very good!\\";\n    pronunciation = \\"/e\\U026as/\\";\n    pronunciationMp3 = ace;\n    word = Ace;\n})\"\n)"
>   )}, [conflictList: <__NSArrayM 0x7f972401eaf0>(
>   NSConstraintConflict (0x7f9721c9cf00) for constraint (
>       word
>   ): database:  (entity: Slang; id: 0xd000000000040000  ; data: ), conflictedObjects: (
>       " (entity: Slang; id: 0xd0000000018c0000  ; data: {\n    explain = \"Excellent! Very good!\";\n    pronunciation = \"/e\U026as/\";\n    pronunciationMp3 = ace;\n    word = Ace;\n})"
>   )
>   )
>   ]

Here is the code I use to save track into core data:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
            let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Track", inManagedObjectContext:context)
            let newTrack = Track(entity:entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
            do {
            newTrack.title = self.thisActivity.title!
            newTrack.star = self.thisActivity.star!
            newTrack.dodate = NSDate()
            newTrack.webpic = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.thisActivity.picture!)!
            newTrack.uptext = ""
            newTrack.uppic = ""

            try context.save()
            SweetAlert().showAlert("Done!", subTitle: "Save to your track!", style: AlertStyle.Success)
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Track already existed in coredata \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                SweetAlert().showAlert("Sorry!", subTitle: "You have saved before!", style: AlertStyle.Success)
                context.deleteObject(newTrack)
            }
```

Looking forward to listen solution from you guys

Comment: I started to get this type of error. Did you found solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have a constraint that says that the `word` field must be unique. This means that when you insert a new track you either need to use a new word or delete the old record. Lots of info here: http://dorianroy.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-implement-unique-constraints-in-core-data-with-ios-9/

Comment: But the thing is that the track and the slang entities don't relate to each other.
Yesterday I was thinking about maybe if 2 entities that don't have any relationship to each other need to have different data model?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many ways and finally this way work for me.
I created 2 data models (one for Slang, one for Track) then create 2 core data stacks for them :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `mergePolicy` for the context, e.g.:

```
context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
```

This lets Core Data know what to do when it encounters merge conflicts.